# Why does my Adobe Creative Cloud package fail to install on Windows 7?

Tags: installation, adobe

I'm using the Adobe Creative Cloud Packager to build an installation package containing all or most of the available applications (as opposed to specific individual applications) for deployment on end-user workstations.

This install package runs successfully on Windows 10, but fails with error 1603 ("A fatal error occurred during installation") on Windows 7.  The installer runs for a long time before failing, and appears to be installing at least some of the applications the package contains, but these installations are rolled back and when the installer finally exits none of the applications in the package are present.

The log file (PDApp.log) may contain the following messages:

> The HDPIM Setup Process return code is (190).Stopping the installation process.
>
> Product Media (ESHR, 0.3.0) installation failed ...

What's going on and is there any way of stopping it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs when the installation package includes Project Felix, whose [system requirements](https://helpx.adobe.com/beta/project-felix/system-requirements.html) include Windows 10 as the minimum supported operating system.  You can work around the problem by excluding Project Felix from the package.

Unfortunately, the Creative Cloud Packager does not include information about which specific applications have unusual minimum requirements, and the installation log does not appear to include information about which application has caused the failure, so it is necessary to either research each application individually or to resort to a process of elimination to determine where the problem lies.